# Made a stupid mistake at work, how can I improve?

Tags: mistakes, reputation

I'm an SDE 2 (little more than 4 yoe) at a FAANG company and recently I merged a pull request (with approval) to prod. It was a very small change that called a data store. The underlying package that called the store was doing a validation check on some properties, and I didn't pass those properties which caused an NPE in PROD.

I'm a recent hire to this company (about 1-2 months) and we are in the midst of a tight deadline. Since I joined, I completed about 5-6 PRs of varying size without much context and my manager recognized that despite not really being given much context I have figured out what to do and done the right thing. We are a fairly large team and he is very busy, so I can only take him at his word and I'm sure he wasn't reviewing PRs himself or anything.

The reason I'm worried is that: 1) the company I work for is notorious for being tough on devs and isn't shy about penalizing people and 2) believe it or not, this is the first big mistake I've made in my career. I've worked at other large companies, and I'm not saying I've written perfect code, but rather any mistake I made was caught before it was merged to PROD, either by my own testing or my own diligence or by someone else's diligence in reviewing the pull requests.

I know how it could have been avoided. Basically I should have just checked the database call implementation and I would've easily seen the validation checks. Also, the unit test I wrote didn't account for this path. I guess I got lazy and assumed what I was doing was right, I also had major tunnel vision and hyperfocused on implementing one specific thing, and also I just really wanted to merge the pull request quickly. But I'm just worried now that I've really damaged my rep with my manager and my team members. If I was a more established engineer within the team and company it probably wouldn't be as big of a deal, but it looks really bad as someone just coming in to make this kind of mistake, especially since it was a fairly obvious issue.

Comment: IMO you're not a real developer unless you deleted at least one production database ;-) But seriously, this could as well be an oversight by whoever tested the application, right? We all make mistakes,  the main thing to consider is how you handle it afterwards. You *did* fix it, right? Btw, I've been a developer for over 20 years, but I have no idea what faang, sde 2 or npe mean.

Comment: @Berend, FAANG is a general term for the Big Tech companies. The acronym itself stands for Facebook/Apple/Amazon/Netflix/Google. OP works for one of those, or a similar company.

Comment: @SethR thanks, I also looked it up in the mean time. In general I think it'd be better to avoid these sort of business specific acronyms here.

Comment: @Berend SDE 2 is a level for software engineer and NPE is null pointer exception. Also I did not fix the issue, the on-call engineer did. I found out about it this morning when I saw the pull request.

Comment: SDE, YOE, FAANG, NPE, PROD, PR, etc., etc. This isn't a software/developer focused site. Maybe use plain English for the people who don't know what those acronyms stand for?

Comment: Since you made this mistake, have you heard anything from the team lead, senior dev, or manager yet ? What action has been taken agains you (nothing at all ? just a minor chat from the team lead ? verbal warning from the manager ? official written warning ?) If a company makes a SDE 2 worry too much about such a mistake, should you plan to work for them for a long time ?

Comment: @Job_September_2020 not directly, I saw it on our internal chat application. to which the on-call engineer and my manager replied, but my manager hasn't reached out to me directly. I apologized to the on-call engineer who had to fix that and then mentioned it briefly in standup but nothing happened beyond that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Learn from the issue, make sure it never happens again, and move on.

For your own education, write a note on what happened, how it happened, and why it won't happen again - you can bring that with you to your next review, and show your manager how you changed your processes.

Also, consider that it's not just your fault. A single developer in a large company should never have been able to merge their own PR without review - so either the process is broken, or the reviewer missed the issue also. The pre deploy integration testing also didn't catch it, so there's an issue there. The processes and people all failed, so you can't be the only person to blame.

Comment: there was a review on the PR, its just that no one including myself caught it.